# Boot LG G3 hard drive from PC

Tags: boot, lg, lg-g3

My father's LG G3 has stopped working. after logo screen it just shuts down.

Is there a way to *boot the phone as only a hard drive* from a PC ?

He has important notes on the phone that he needs to restore.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, because you have to boot up your phone to use the MTP functions like HDD (or External Mass Storage). Probably your father did a **NAND erase**, which delete the boot-up partition.
You could use LG Flash Tool to install the .kdz and make the new partition.

Comment: I certainly don't doubt the first part of what you said. However, the startup issue sounds more probable that it may well be the rampant [LG bootloop issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LG_smartphone_bootloop_issues), which Google (and I) attest also happens to the G3. There's about 1,000 forum topics to search through about it... but the gist seems that some people have found reprieve  by tightening screws, buying a new battery, applying a heat gun/hair drier to the back and pushing the connection tight, etc.

Comment: I have found no fix yet, but haven't tried them all.  Many hints it's hardware related, though seems some loose patterns to software update windows as well.  Regardless, I have found it still intermittently will start  up with a bit of persistent battery removal and replacement, then restart.  To me it seems most likely to start up when cold... and if you can get through the boot and give it a few minutes to allow it to finish loading everything, it will typically maintain more stability.  Enough to connect to computer or wifi (though as symptoms have progressed, I no longer can) and backup.

Comment: I said that because the bootloop problem happens on the next generation (as G4 or Nexus 5X) instead of LG G3. I've got a LG G3 (D855 model) and I went through a problem like this and **I resolve that with a .kdz flash**.
Of course, If the problem still remain, he must contact the support for a motherboard replacement.

Comment: Will certainly have to try that.  But [Android Central](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootloop+lg+g3+site:forums.androidcentral.com&client=firefox-b-1-ab&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwip0ana3YDYAhWFKCYKHb25Bp0QrQIINCgEMAA&biw=1366&bih=635) for example shows a lot of discussion about boot loop (1390 results for G3, 1740 for G4, so seems perhaps significant)... and [Youtube](https://www.google.com/search?q=youtube+bootloop+lg+g3&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab) has plenty of videos too.  So certainly, whether it could be the issue.  Hopefully this kdz flash works, thanks for the help!